# cant start apache2 after a reboot

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I cant make apache2 start.
I used nodejs with port 8585 and then i rebooted the server without closing the node instance, from that moment i'm stack with this error:

> - Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                              (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8585
>     (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8000
>     no listening sockets available, shutting down
>     AH00015: Unable to open logs
>     Action 'start' failed.
>     The Apache error log may have more information.

I used this command to check if these port are used `netstat -lnp | grep :8585`
 but with no result.
How would i get apache to run?
I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY i found it,
`grep -ri listen /etc/apache2` and i was surprised when i found a very old config file that uses the same port 8585, i just change it then restart my server and everything was ok. I can't get it, i'm using this file with this port for almost a year with no problem why now??!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have multiple errors.
This is telling me that you have permission problems:

```
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

After using the netstat you should check if the user has the permission to start apache (permission on logs, ports...)

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :<PORT>
```

Comment: i did run this command `netstat -tulpn | grep :8585` but also with no result. for the permission, i used apache2 without changing any config in this pc for 2 years now. so i think the user have all the permissions.

Comment: `drwxr-x---  2 root   adm 4096 Mar 13 06:47 apache2`

Comment: Can Anyone help me?

Comment: You could try `apache2ctl configtest` to verify your config files. You are running all this as root, correct?

Comment: yes i run it with root and as a result i got this Syntax OK

Comment: Is the node instance off? Never worked with it but it seems like you should try to return to your previous environment before running both applications.

Comment: i have no apps running on these ports 8000 or 8585 when i use netstat or top. i cant find anything and the problem is i did not change anything in my config. i closed everything but i still get this error!!

Comment: Can you change your apps' ports? By doing so, you could rule out any apache issue (if it works) and focus on the system itself

Comment: I'm glad to know that, but i think you should post an answer here showing what was wrong and what you did to solve it. Cheers

Comment: i did that, but i can't make it as a answer :\